# Срезание углов блока на CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть задача, сделать кнопку в виде стрелки, как на изображении. Есть ли способы срезать уголки кнопки на CSS?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [css triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

Comment: [и вот](http://jhaurawachsman.com/2013/css-triangles-border-stroke/)

Comment: такое ощущение, что я уже отвечал на такой вопрос...

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, причем мне кажется я видел уже _несколько_ раз подобные вопросы

Answer (score 4):

```css
*, :befoer, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  float: left;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 1em;
  background: green;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-right: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 2.2em;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -1.25em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Arrow Arrow Arrow Arrow Arrow</div>
```

Comment: Угол там не 90*, а скажем 100*. Тогда квадратный блок не прокатит.

Comment: @KirillSemenov, тогда transform умеет и неквадратные делать, только считать больше придётся.

Answer (score 0):

вместо "срезания" уголков можно составить стрелку из двух блоков:

```css
.left, .right {display: inline-block; box-sizing: border-box;}
.left {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-right: none;
}
.right {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: black;
}
.right:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  left: -25px; top: -21px;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 21px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: обводочка так не получится :)

Comment: @splash58, ну почему? :-) второй треугольник под низ цвета обводки и чуть побольще :)

Comment: @Grundy я вот сразу бы и не написал. хотя понимаю, что можно. это z index надо?

Comment: @splash58, вроде не обязательно, главное чтобы подложка шла раньше по разметке

Comment: про обводку не подумал. поправил ответ с учетом обводки