# Как с помощью css сделать шестиугольный блок на всю ширину?

Tags: css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать данный блок с помощью css?

Интересует именно через css, так как блок должен занимать 100% ширины экрана.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Срезание углов блока на CSS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488778/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-css)

Comment: @Grundy, явно же не дубликат.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему? те же самые треугольники, только с двух сторон

Comment: @Grundy, неа, эти же резиновые.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему резиновые? единственное отличие что они сверху и снизу а не сбоку

Comment: @Grundy, потому что ширина 100%, а не фиксированная как там.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35330/discussion-between-grundy-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про `transform` [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Поддержка [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column;
  -ms-flex-flow: column;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 450px;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content .block1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f4e8d4;
}
.content .block1:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  border-top: 10px solid #f7efe1;
}
.content .block1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  border-top: 10px solid #f7efe1;
}
.content .block2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f4e8d4;
}
.content .block2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(10deg);
  transform: skewY(10deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f7efe1;
}
.content .block2:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: inherit;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-10deg);
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f7efe1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```